# Changing from HTML4 to HTML5 because of accessibility?

Tags: html, accessibility, html4

I'm working for the **public sector** and I had to take over a web project from my superior. The page is already made accessible to people with disabilities.

While making some changes I thought about changing from **HTML4** to **HTML5** because I heard it has some new, better aspects for the accessibility.

Does the change really pay off? Or is it just wasted time to convert the code?

Comment: What's wrong with the current page?

Comment: There is nothing wrong, it's ok and working well. But because of some new tasks i have to do with the page and the code i had to take over is really bad, i thought i should remake the whole page. And with that point i thought about chaning to html5

Answer (score 3):

HTML5 brings with it a large array of semantic elements that give the user agent further insight into how the page is laid out. It is definitely worth it and shouldn't be too time consuming especially if your styles are decent and don't rely on tag types. You will basically be replacing a bunch of `<div>`s with their semantic counterparts.

For example, here are some of the new tags in HTML5:

- `<section>`
- `<nav>`
- `<article>`
- `<aside>`
- `<hgroup>`
- `<header>`
- `<footer>`
- `<time>`
- `<mark>`

The other parts of HTML5 like CSS3, local storage, etc. don't really have accessibility benefits.

I suggest reading up more about what all these tags actually mean to make sure you're using them correctly. There were also other changes like clear meanings for the `<b>`, `<em>` and `<strong>` tags.

### Support

Some browsers like IE6 (not sure about IE7) don't like these new tags and will mangle the page when used. You can include a polyfill library like Modernizr to fix this up, simply include the script and everything works!

### Further reading

- [Dive into HTML - Semantics](http://diveintohtml5.info/semantics.html)
- [HTML5 Doctor](http://html5doctor.com/lets-talk-about-semantics/)

Answer (score 0):

While html5 is a great standard to aim for, many browsers still don't support the newer tags/markup....enter ARIA or [WAI-ARIA (Accessible Rich Internet Applications Suite).](http://www.w3.org/WAI/intro/aria)

[Clarissa Peterson's website](http://www.clarissapeterson.com/2012/11/html5-accessibility/) gives a nice real-world example of html5 v ARIA. See the section titled **HTML5 & ARIA**.